# How to get Image Orientation without loading the UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My question is quite straightforward, I want to get the orientation of an image, but I don't want to use `[UIImage imageWithData:]` because it consumes memory and is potentially slow. So, what would be the solution? The images are saved in the app's documents folder rather than `ALAssetsLibrary`.

PS: happy new year guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use lower level Quartz functions. Read in the first 2K or 4K of the image into a NSData object, then pass that data to an incremental image creator, and ask it for the orientation. If you don't get it, read in a larger chunk. JPGs almost always have the metadata in the first 2K of data (maybe 4K, been a while since I wrote this code):

```
    {
        CGImageSourceRef imageSourcRef = CGImageSourceCreateIncremental(NULL);
        CGImageSourceUpdateData(imageSourcRef, (__bridge CFDataRef)data, NO);

        CFDictionaryRef dict = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSourcRef, 0, NULL);
        if(dict) {
            //CFShow(dict);
            self.properties = CFBridgingRelease(dict);
            if(!self.orientation) {
                self.orientation = [[self.properties objectForKey:@"Orientation"] integerValue];
            }
        }
        CFRelease(imageSourcRef);           
    }
```